# (Scrapy) Generate Request / Generate & execute Request / Execute Request

Tags: python, scrapy, request, yield

I am studying scrapy examples at https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-crawl-infinite-scrolling-pages-using-python/

Regarding to **yield Request** of the Scrapy solution code in there, I am very confused.

There are three **yield Request**s. Sometime a **Request** is just generated, sometime it is generated and executed, sometime it is just executed.

Could you advice me what are the differences between them please?

Thank you!.

```
def parse_list_page(self, response):
    next_link = response.xpath(
        "//a[@class='page-link next-page']/@href").extract_first()
    if next_link:
        url = response.url
        next_link = url[:url.find('?')] + next_link

        ################################
        # Generate and Execute Request
        ################################

        yield Request(                           
            url=next_link,
            callback=self.parse_list_page
        )

    for req in self.extract_product(response):
        ################################
        #Just Execute Request
        ################################
        yield req       

def extract_product(self, response):
    links = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-lg-8']//div[@class='card']/a/@href").extract()
    for url in links:
        result = parse.urlparse(response.url)
        base_url = parse.urlunparse(
            (result.scheme, result.netloc, "", "", "", "")
        )
        url = parse.urljoin(base_url, url)

        ################################
        #Just Generate Request
        ################################

        yield Request (
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse_product_page
        )

def parse_product_page(self, response):
    logging.info("processing " + response.url)
    yield None
```

Comment: Can you fix the link so we can see the example you are using. There isn't really any difference between the requests, it is just the control flow of the spider.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the link. Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the [figure here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow) useful for answering your question.

The `yield`s from the `parse_list_page` method are yielding requests back to the "Engine" (step 7 in the figure). The `yield` in `extract_product` is yielding back to `parse_list_page`. `parse_list_page` then immediately yields them back to the engine.

Note that all the code in `extract_product` could also just go into `parse_list_page` to make one single method. Having two methods just nicely separates the logic.

[image: scrapy data flow]